# Boost (signals) library not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am building ROS on Mac OSX from source, and when trying to run rosmake -a I get the following message for a number of packages:

```
ld: library not found for -l:/usr/local/lib/libboost_signals-mt.dylib
```

Boost 1.52 is installed and that file does exist, should I install a different version of boost? Or is something else perhaps going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54437/boost-(signals)-library-not-found/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-06**:
Just a small update, I tried installing boost 1.49, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, I do not know why, but it appears some .pc files in ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/pkgconfig contained links to libraries in the form of :

```
-l:/path/to/lib/lib.dylib
```

While it should have been :

```
-l/path/to/lib/lib.dylib
```

(minus the ':'). I removed all the ':' from these pc files and that fixed it. Perhaps I should open a ticket?

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-08**:
This should not be a problem, I just rebuilt the desktop variant last night (with the latest XCode and brew packages) and never ran into this problem. What version of OS X and XCode are you using?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-22**:
I'm having same issue on OS X 10.7.5 and Xcode 4.6. Replacement of `-l:` with the following command solves it: `find *.pc -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i .bak 's/\-l:/\-l/g'`

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-28**:
If you've installed to */opt/ros/groovy*, the following command should do the job. `cd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/pkgconfig ; find . -name  *.pc -print0 | xargs -0 sudo sed -i .bak 's/\-l:/\-l/g'`

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2014-10-04**:
Just have had the same problem with Indigo!